# How to prove the difference of convergent sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For this question, I'm not sure how to complete the proof. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Let b, c, l, m ∈ R. Let f, g : R → R be functions. Suppose that
$\lim_{ x \to \infty} f(x) = l$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = m$
 Give a complete and accurate $\epsilon$ − N proof that $\lim_{ x \to \infty}(2bf(x)-3cg(x))$ exists.

$\lim_{ x \to \infty}(2bf(x)-3cg(x)) = 2bl-3cm$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $ n > N_1$ st $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon/2$. Suppose $n > N_2$ st $|g(x)-m| < \epsilon/2$

Pick N = $max(N_1, N_2)$

$|2bf(x)-3cg(x) -(2bl-3cm)|$

$ = |2bf(x)-3cg(x)-2bl+3cm|$

$ = |2bf(x)-2bl| + |3cg(x)-3cm|$

$ = |2b||f(x)-l| + |3c||g(x)-m|< |2b|\frac{\epsilon}{|2b|*2} + |3c|\frac{\epsilon}{|3c|*2} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

Comment: Look at your last line - can you justify the inequality?

Comment: Are you talking about the last line?

Comment: Yup, I've edited.

Comment: We are trying to canel out the $|2b|$ and $|3c|$ aren't we? so that it can add up to epsilon?

Comment: That's the goal, yes

Comment: So what's wrong with it?

Comment: That inequality is incorrect - I see why you've tried to do it, but it's incorrect as written

Comment: So how do I fix it? What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76248/discussion-between-b-mehta-and-dg123).